# Example of when we need to use a cursor in SQL that cannot be solved with set based approaches

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can someone please give an example of when we need to use a cursor in SQL that *cannot* be solved with a set based approaches.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cursor is often used when you need to do an action on a per row basis. Which is something we'd often relegate to other tools outside of the DBMS. In general the strength of the DBMS lies in set based approaches for data. However.. to give an example.

Say you have a table where some other process writes mail messages to be stored and sent at a later date. Perhaps multiple SQL jobs running and each writes their own status, then when next morning comes or the server load is very low, the DBMS is expected to send these on its own.

Setting up an example table with some data:

```
CREATE TABLE outgoingMessages
(
    recipient VARCHAR(MAX),
    subject NVARCHAR(255),
    message NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.outgoingMessages (recipient,subject,message)
VALUES
('foo@bar.com', N'An email', N'Procedure dbo.Foo ran with statuscode X'),
('foo@bar.com', N'An email', N'Procedure dbo.Bar ran with statuscode Y'),
('manager@bar.com', N'An email', N'Data synchronisation had problems, ask foo')
```

Then as a theoretical end step/end job, we have a process that goes over the table and handles all built up messages.

```
/* Scheduled job */ 
DECLARE mailCursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT * FROM dbo.outgoingMessages;

DECLARE @mailRecipient VARCHAR(MAX); 
DECLARE @mailSubject NVARCHAR(255); 
DECLARE @mailMessage NVARCHAR(MAX);

OPEN mailCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM mailCursor INTO 
@mailRecipient, @mailSubject, @mailMessage 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  PRINT @mailRecipient + ' ' + @mailSubject + ' ' + @mailMessage

  EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
  @profile_name = N'defaultMailprofile',
  @recipients = @mailRecipient,
  @subject = @mailSubject,
  @body = @mailMessage


  FETCH NEXT FROM mailCursor INTO 
  @mailRecipient, @mailSubject, @mailMessage

END

CLOSE mailCursor; 
DEALLOCATE mailCursor;
```

This makes the database print out all lines individually and send a mail to the specified variables (calls another stored procedure for it) for each line in the table. I would say this line of operation, taking data for each row and manipulating it further or using it as variables for another procedure is a more common usecase.

```
/* Print results */
foo@bar.com An email Procedure dbo.Foo ran with statuscode X
foo@bar.com An email Procedure dbo.Bar ran with statuscode Y
manager@bar.com An email Data synchronisation had problems, ask foo
```

You can think of a table with perhaps built up API calls by other automated processes, then to be executed at a later date.

Are cursors common? No. You should always consider their usecases and ideally use a different approach. But if you need to do something for each line, and potentially jump backwards based on conditions. Cursors allow you to do so inside the DBMS and they're a powerful tool.